# CSS - wordpress how to change the drop down element's font style

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, frontend

I'm trying to change the font of the elements on all my drop down lists. I want to keep the font of the title of the drop down list but change the font of the elements inside it. I'm using a present in wordpress so I took the class code from google devtool but I tried to write the css . I can't change the html code because are presets.

```html
<select id="pa_mat" class="" 
name="attribute_pa_mat" 
data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_mat" 
data-show_option_none="yes">
<option value="">Elige una opción</option>
<option value="foam" class="attached enabled">FOAM</option>
<option value="pvc" class="attached enabled">PVC</option></select>

css

option.attached enabled{
            font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

I'm trying to do something as the picture attached.

Example

[image]

thanks in advance to everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to chain the CSS selectors, like:

```
option.attached.enabled {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/39gd2mtq/

What you currently have  (`option.attached enabled`) is looking for a child element called `enabled` within `option.attached`.